# JQuery duplicate a radio button group

Tags: jquery

I am trying to duplicate a radio button group in my application by using JQuery. But I am not able to figure out how to do this. I saw that most solutions suggest to increment the duplication number and set the name attribute.

My form for the duplication is as below. Doesn't the name on array (**educationDetails[mark_type][]**) gives the unique name? The form is in Laravel Collective.

Target to be copied

```
<!-- Target to be copied -->
    <div class="education-fields">
    </div>

<!-- Source to copy -->
    <div class="education-fields-template>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4 mt-4 form-inline">
                <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                    {!! Form::radio('educationDetails[mark_type][]', 'GPA', false, ['class' => 'form-check-input']); !!}
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="gpa">GPA</label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                    {!! Form::radio('educationDetails[mark_type][]', 'Percentage', true, ['class' => 'form-check-input']); !!}

                    <label class="form-check-label" for="percentage">Percentage</label>
                </div>
                <label for="subject" class="text-gray percentage-label">Percentage
                    <small>*</small>
                </label>
                {!! Form::text('educationDetails[mark][]', null, ['class' => 'form-control ml-2 percentage-field', 'placeholder' => 'Enter percentage']) !!}
            </div>
    </div>
```

Any idea to duplicate this piece of the element without manually setting the name will be very helpful.

My JQuery code

```
let educationFormField = '<div class="row education-fields">' + $('.education-fields-template').html() + '</div>';
        $('body').find('.education-fields:last').after(educationFormField);
```

Answer (score 0):

So two first things for starters:

- You are missing the end quote here: `<div class="education-fields-templat>`
- And this is not JavaScript/JQuery nor HTML, is it?: `{!! [...] !!}` Just for the next time please provide a sample that acutally runs ^^ :)

However just copy the elements `innerHTML` to the others:

**JavaScript:**

```js
document.getElementById("copyButton").addEventListener("click", () => {
  document.getElementsByClassName("education-fields")[0].innerHTML =
  document.getElementsByClassName("education-fields-template")[0].innerHTML;
});
```

```html
<!-- Source to copy -->
<p>Education Fields Template</p>
<div class="education-fields-template">
  <input type="text">
  <input type="text">
</div>
<!-- Button to copy the element -->
<button id="copyButton">Copy!</button>
<!-- Target to be copied -->
<p>Education Fields</p>
<div class="education-fields"></div>
```

And I quickly worked out some jQuery code.. I've never really used it before so **could** be wrong.

**jQuery**

```js
$("#copyButton").click(() => $(".education-fields").html($(".education-fields-template").html()));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Source to copy -->
<p>Education Fields Template</p>
<div class="education-fields-template">
  <input type="text">
  <input type="text">
</div>
<!-- Button to copy the element -->
<button id="copyButton">Copy!</button>
<!-- Target to be copied -->
<p>Education Fields</p>
<div class="education-fields"></div>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I have more than above code in my form. So to show in short I wrote education-fields-template. {!! !!} is not HTML and I mentioned it as Laravel Collective. Also, the example provided by you is not for radio buttons.

Comment: It doesn't matter what is in the HTML? does it? It just copies it. You could also put images in there

Comment: it does not matter. The thing that matters is how to duplicate radio groups, not input fields using an array in the name.

Comment: I don't get what you mean.. My jQuery and JavaScript simply copies the innerHTML. I just couldn't use your code because it would just display as plain text in the browser...

Comment: I already have working code to copy all other elements. I was confused with radio buttons. Can you please try your code with radio buttons if it works correctly or not